# Change label text from another class

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a simple windows form, and a label, from another class I have a loop and I want that every cycle loop the Text propriety of label in form class change, but I can't access it, I tried to make it public but nothing to do.

So how can I change label text from another class?

Comment: In general, even if the Label is public, it's still owned by the Form class, so that's what you need a reference to.

Comment: Do this like *any* Winforms class does it.  How do you know that a Button was clicked?  How do you know that a TextBox's Text changed?  How does your form class know that the label text needs to be updated?  Same way, use an event.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the label as a parameter for form2 constructor, then do what you want on it.

Something like this:

```
#include"form2.h"
class form1{

private: Label^ form1Labl;

private: System::Void button1_Click{

form2^ form2Obj= gcnew form2(form1Labl);

form2Obj->Show();

}

};
```

and in form2 class:

```
class form2{
private: Label^ lableObj;

form2(Label^ l){ 
lableObj=l;
}

// rest of your code to change lableObj->Text propriety.

};
```